# Как получить кол-во записей от команды в redis?

Tags: redis

Есть команда:

```
GEOSEARCH Users FROMLONLAT 12 24 BYRADIUS 2 km ASC
```

от которой я получаю N пользователей в спсике я хочу в графане видеть только саму N.

Не могу найти как взять llen или count.